# winsock, message oriented networking, and type-casting the buffer from recv

Tags: c++, visual-c++, winsock2

Okay, I actually don't have code as of yet because i'm just picking out a framework for the time being, but i'm still a little baffled about how i wish to go about this :.

Server side, i wish to have a class where each instance has a socket and various information identifying each connection. each object will have it's own thread for receiving data. I understand how i'll be implementing most of that, but my confusion starts just as i get to the actual transfer of data between server and client. I'll want to have a bunch of different message structs for specific cases, (for example CONNECT_MSG , DISCONNECT_MSG, POSTTEXT_MSG, etc) and then all i have to do is have a char * point at that struct and then pass it via the send() function.

But as i think on it, it gets a little complicated at that point. Any of those different message types could be sent, and on the receiving end, you will have no idea what you should cast the incoming buffer as. What i was hoping to do is, in the thread of each connection object, have it block until it receives a packet with a message, then dump it into a single queue object managed by the server(mutexes will prevent greediness) and then the server will process each message in FIFO order independent of the connection objects.

I havn't written anything yet, but let me write a little something to illustrate my setup.

```
#define CONNECT 1000

struct GENERIC_MESSAGE
{
    int id;
}

struct CONNECT_MESSAGE : public GENERIC_MESSAGE
{
    m_username;
}

void Connection::Thread()
{

    while(1)
    {
         char buffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];    // some constant(probably 2048)
         recv(m_socket, buffer, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
         MESSAGE_GENERIC * msg = reinterpret_cast<MESSAGE_GENERIC *> (buffer);
         server->queueMessage(msg);
    }

}

void Server::QueueMessage(MESSAGE_GENERIC * msg)
{
    messageQueue.push(msg);
}

void Server::Thread()
{
    while(1)
    {
         if(!messageQueue.empty())
              ProcessMessages();
         else
              Sleep(1);
    }
}

void Server::ProcessMessages()
{
     for(int i = 0; i < messageQueue.size(); i++)
     {
          switch(messageQueue.front()->id)
          {
                case CONNECT:
                {
                     // the part i REALLY don't like
                     CONNECT_MESSAGE * msg = static_cast<CONNECT_MESSAGE *>(messageQueue.front() );
                     // do the rest of the processing on connect
                     break;
                }
                // other cases for the other message types
          }
          messageQueue.pop();
     }
}
```

Now if you've been following up until now, you realize just how STUPID and fragile this is. it casts to the base class, passes that pointer to a queue, and then just assumes that the pointer is still valid from the other thread, and even then whether or not the remaining buffer after the pointer for the rest of the derived class will always be valid afterward for casting, but i have yet to find a correct way of doing this. I am wide open for ANY suggestions, either making this work, or an entirely different messaging design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you write even a line of code, design the protocol that will be used on the wired. Decide what a message will consist of at the byte level. Decide who sends first, whether messages are acknowledged, how receivers identify message boundaries, and so on. Decide how the connection will be kept active (if it will be), which side will close first, and so on. Then write the code around the specification.

Do not tightly associate how you store things in memory with how you send things on the wire. These are two very different things with two very different sets of requirements.

Of course, feel free to adjust the protocol specification as you write the code.

Comment: i actually had most of this ironed out. All messages will consist of an id for the type of message, and the rest would be variable depending on what the id was. either can send first, and either can receive simultaneously. it will be tcp/ip so messages are acknowledged, not sure what you mean by message boundaries. Connect will be kept active until a disconnect message is received, and either client or server side can send a disconnect message and they will handle it accordingly. Right now, the only hangup is that variability in data type with the sent messages.

Comment: Define each message payload at the byte level. Define how the receiver will find the boundaries between messages (where one message ends and the next begins).

Comment: that's actually what i'm trying to avoid with the casting and messages, i have done some winsock programming before, and found that elaborate parsing schemes at the byte level were just as precarious as what i'm trying to do now. trying to split up a single char * buffer into multiple objects was always hit and miss. now i'm trying to restrict it so that i only have one message object per buffer, that can be casted to a type and the data now all laid out in a single compliant object, but this doesn't seem to be working either.

Comment: You don't want to avoid it. A TCP connection is a stream of bytes. You need to define a protocol in terms of bytes. You may find it hit or miss, but at least it's possible to debug it -- just compare the bytes generated with your protocol specification.

Comment: yeh, i wouldn't even call what i had up there a protocol specification :\ . Just wondering if a method similar was even possible. When you say stream of bytes though, that makes me think that maybe i can treat it like c++ treats streams, have a buffer, and then a char * marking your current parse position, and create objects from that point and moving the char * to the end of what was just parsed out. I'll see if i can work something out. thanks for the constructive critcism though, i think i'm sort of in the right mindset now.

Comment: Just make sure to lay them out, byte by byte, for sending over the network according to the protocol specification. Make sure you *have* a specification at the byte level and make sure your code arranges the bytes to follow the specification.